# Select all classes using jquery with the same inner html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to be able to change the innerHTML of a class, based on the innerHTML of that class, however, the text of that class is different from regular text (has it's own css and what not), and it needs to retain such properties, so I can't use text() 
 I have

```
<span class="special">John</span>
```

And I need to change all classes with the special attribute, and innerHTML of John, to Jack.

however, for whatever reason

```
$("[special='John']").html('<span class="special">Jack</span>');
```

is not working. I'm sure it's just a silly mistake, but thank you in advance.

Comment: "John" is not an *attribute* it is the *element's content* ([1](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-content)). Please clarify.

Comment: DOM selection isn't done based on "HTML". The class is just an attribute of the element. The CSS of the element isn't part of the text of the class. The "special" is the value of the class attribute. Your attempt looks more like a guess. That's not a proper approach to learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
$(".special:contains('John')").html('Jack');
```

Or, if the text needs to be equal to, rather than contains:

```
$('.special').filter(function() {return $(this).text() == "John";}).html('Jack');
```